# unable to search within List of Strings - Objectify 3.1

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am not sure why my following Objectify code is not working for searching within list of strings.

following is my entity class:

```
public class Employee
{
    @Id private Long id;
    .
    .
    private List <String> location;
    .
    .
    getter() .. setter()
}



Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();

List<Employee> employees= (List<Employee>) ofy.query(Employee.class).filter("location IN", "newyork");
```

employees list is empty .. even if i have Employee records with location arraylist containing "newyork"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List<Employee> employees= (List<Employee>) ofy.query(Employee.class).filter("location", "newyork");
```

The IN operator in filter tells the query to search for Employees within a list of locations. Since you are only searching for one location, there is no need for this operator.

Comment: Hello pipng13579, filter("location", "newyork") works for 1st content of List. However, I would like to filter on all contents of List. So for example, my location List looks like = [newyork, new jersey, vermont, penn, ...] and i would like to filter on 1 selected location. Any idea, how can i achieve that.

Comment: filter("location", "newyork") does exactly what you want - it finds Employees who have "newyork" in the location list (anywhere). This is how indexed collections in GAE work.